# Python: Plot of categorical values in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, data-science

I'm using this lines of code to show count plots for each categorical value in df, however it is only showing me a countplot for 'Parch'

```
 for column in df.select_dtypes(include='category'):
    if df[column].nunique() > 1:
        sns.countplot(y=column,data=df)
plt.show()
df.dtypes
```

Result: [image: plot]

```
   Survived    category
Pclass      category
Sex         category
Age          float64
SibSp       category
Parch       category
Ticket        object
Fare         float64
Embarked      object
Title         object
dtype: object
```

How dataframe look like: [image]
How description of my categorical columns looks like: [image]

Comment: Put `plt.show()` at the same indentation as the `sns.countplot`

Comment: `df.hist(bins=6,figsize=(10,6),grid=False)` ?